# How to change color of detail disclosure button for table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to change the color of detail disclosure button of a table cell. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> You have to create a custom *UIButton* and set it as cell's *accessoryView*.

Your *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* will look something like the following,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //...

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

        UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
        [myAccessoryButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_red_accessory_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell setAccessoryView:myAccessoryButton];
        [myAccessoryButton release];

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Change the tint of your tableview and cell will work too.

Comment: This MUST be the right answer. Simple and right. To change ONLY the color of the 'i' icon we simply set the tint color of the table containing the cell.

Comment: This works for every default accessory view except the disclosure indicator. For that, you will have to provide a custom accessory view.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the Global Tint Colour. This will change the default colour to the colour you change in you app. This will change the colour of accessory button to the colour you select.

Answer (score 1):

As you got best code with you from simon: what i did is:

```
UIButton *trackImageOnMap=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420, 5, 40, 50)];
[trackImageOnMap setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"track_map_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[trackImageOnMap setTag:iId];
[trackImageOnMap addTarget:self action:@selector(trackImageOnMapButtonTouched:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[trackImageOnMap setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[cell setAccessoryView:trackImageOnMap];
```

this implements some extra properties along with required one..