# Change color of detail disclosure button dynamically in code

Tags: ios, colors, indicator, disclosure

I know similar question(s) have been asked before, but most answers say create a new detail disclosure button image with the required color (e.g. [How to change color of detail disclosure button for table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655106/how-to-change-color-of-detail-disclosure-button-for-table-cell)).

I want to be able to change it to any color I choose, dynamically, at run-time, so using a pre-configured image is not viable.

From reading around, I think there may be a few ways to do this, but I'm not sure which is the best, or exactly how to do it:

1. Draw the required color circle in code and overlay with an image of shadow round outside of circle and arrow right (with clear alpha channel for rest, so drawn color circle is still visible)
2. Add image of shadow round outside of circle in UIImageView, and using as a mask, flood fill within this shadow circle, then overlay the arrow.
3. Add greyscale image, mask it with itself, and overlay the required color (e.g. http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/iphone-how-to-dynamically-color-a-uiimage), then overlay that with arrow image.

What is the best way, and does anyone have any code showing exactly how to do it ?

Comment: I use option 3 in my own app. Works quite well.

Comment: @rmaddy - Any chance of posting the greyscale image of the detail disclosure button without the arrow (both non-retina and retina versions, if possible) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following helper method to tint a grayscale image. It takes the grayscale image, the tint color, and an option mask image used to ensure the tint only happens in part of the grayscale image. This method also ensure the new image has the same (if any) resizable insets as the original image.

```
+ (UIImage *)tintImage:(UIImage *)baseImage withColor:(UIColor *)color mask:(UIImage *)maskImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(baseImage.size, NO, baseImage.scale);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, baseImage.size.width, baseImage.size.height);

    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    if (maskImage) {
        CGContextClipToMask(ctx, area, maskImage.CGImage);
    } else {
        CGContextClipToMask(ctx, area, baseImage.CGImage);
    }

    [color set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, area);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeOverlay);

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, baseImage.CGImage);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (!UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(baseImage.capInsets, UIEdgeInsetsZero)) {
        newImage = [newImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:baseImage.capInsets];
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

Here is the non-retina grayscale detail disclosure image:
[image]

Here is the retina version:
[image]

Here is the non-retina mask (between the quotes - it's mostly white):
"[image]"

And the retina mask (between the quotes:
"[image]"

Comment: Many thanks @rmaddy. You're a legend!    I know I didn't specifically ask for it in my question, but I had planned on overlaying the arrow image, so I could then also use it to create a similar dynamically colored button with a tick, one with a cross, and a third without any arrow/tick/cross (ie. just the colored circular image with white border).    Don't suppose you have similar images/masks with a tick and also with a cross, and a plain one ?     I'm just going to test your code and if all works as expected, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: While your solution works for coloring the image, there are a couple of cosmetic issues: 1) It loses the highlight arc on the top half of the image so the color appears solid.  2) After the tint, the part where the new color meets the inner border on the left, right and bottom does not look as nice as the original greyscale image.

Comment: For issue (1), the highlight is not lost with all colors, only some.  For (2), it may just be my eyes, but it doesn't look quite as nice with all colors.  Marking this as answer as although it's not perfect, it's good enough for me, for now. I think a slightly better solution, which keeps the highlight with all colors is to draw a solid color for the circle, and use overlay images for the surrounding border, highlight, and symbol (ie. chevron/arrow, tick, cross, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider also using an icon font in a label instead of an image. Something like [glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com). Then you can set the text colour to whatever you want. You also have good options for scaling. The cost is that you don't have quite such precise control in some cases but it should work well for your case.